# Does a number as a character take less space than a number as an integer?

Tags: java, char, numbers, int

so for example does

```
char x = '1';
```

take less space than

```
int x = 1;
```

or is it the same?

Comment: If you want to have a single digit taking as little space as possible, you should use the `byte` datatype. It takes half as much space as a `char`.

Comment: The best you can do here is a single bit. A single bit can represent either zero or 1. You can pack 32 of them in an `int`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`char` takes 2 bytes and `int` takes 4 bytes.

So, yes. `char` takes less space.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: On a 64 bits architecture it’s probably only relevant if you can pack more than one of them into a word, though. And all things being equal, the instructions generated to take them out of the word again can fill much more than the data itself.

Comment: Wow. Thanks . :+)

Comment: Everywhere I look I hear the opposite that ```int``` takes up less space then char. Is this language/ database specific? For example does char take up less space than int in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

A char needs 16 bits.
A int needs 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

`Char` stores character constants in the memory. It assumes a size of `2 bytes`, but basically it can hold only a single character because char stores **unicode** character sets. It has a minimum value of `‘u0000’` (or 0) and a maximum value of `‘uffff’` (or 65,535, inclusive).But integers are `4 bytes`.

Others primitive types range and size;

```
Type            Size            Range of values that can be stored
byte            1 byte          −128 to 127
short           2 bytes         −32768 to 32767
int             4 bytes         −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
long            8 bytes         9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to9,223,372,036,854,755,807
float           4 bytes         3.4e−038 to 3.4e+038
double          8 bytes         1.7e−308 to 1.7e+038
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Integer` and `Character` class, there is a `SIZE` field, which means the using space (bit). Integer use 32 bits, and Character use 16 bits.